# Autoconverting template< T> to template<const T>

Tags: c++, string, c++11

This piece below is supposed to be primarily for a string view with `T={char, const char}` being the primary intended template instantiation target.

The cmp function is supposed to compare the views analogously to `strcmp`. 
The problem is that while `char*` happily converts to `const char*` I don't know how to get `SVec<char>` to convert to `SVec<const char>` just as happily.

The last line (`cout<<(cmp(rv, rvc));`) won't compile. I have to do the convertion explicitly (`cmp(SVec<const char>(rv), rvc)`). Can it be automatic like with `char*` to `const char*`?

The code (much simplified):

```
template <typename T>
class SVec {
    protected:
        T* begin_;
        size_t size_;
    public:

        SVec(T* begin, size_t size)         : begin_(begin), size_(size)            {};
        SVec(T* begin, T* end)                  : begin_(begin), size_(end-begin) {};
        SVec(T* begin)                          : begin_(begin) { while (*(begin++)) {}; size_ = begin - 1 - begin_;    }
                                                //^null element indicates the end
        ///Conversion
        operator SVec<const T>() const { return SVec<const T>(begin_, size_); }
};

//General lexicographic compare
template <typename T>
inline int cmp(const SVec<const T>& l, const SVec<const T> & r){
    return 1;
}

//Char specialization
template <> inline int cmp<char>(const SVec<const char>& l, const SVec<const char>& r){
    return 1;
}
//Explicit instantiation
template int cmp<char>(const SVec<const char>& l, const SVec<const char>& r);

#include <iostream>

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    char ar[] = "st";
    SVec<char> sv = ar;
    SVec<const char> svc = "str";

    cout<<(cmp(SVec<const char>(sv), svc));

    cout<<(cmp(sv, svc));
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not conversion, but deduction. User-defined conversions are not considered for type deduction, hence `cmp(const SVec<const T>&` fails to match `const T` with `char` in the line `cmp(sv, svc)` (there is no `T` such that `const T` is equal to `char`).

Comment: @dyp Thanks. `cmp<char>(...)` fixes it.

Comment: @dyp can you just make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing you should probably do is make `cmp` a Koenig operator.

Then we can tag dispatch between the char and non-char versions:

```
template <typename T>
class SVec {
  private:
    static T* find_end(T* in) {
      // I think while(*in)++in; would be better
      // then the end is the null, not one-past-the-null.
      while(*in++) {};
      return in;
    }
  protected:
    T* begin_ = nullptr;
    size_t size_ = 0;
  public:
    SVec() = default;
    SVec(SVec const&) = default;
    SVec(T* begin, size_t size) : begin_(begin), size_(size) {};
    SVec(T* begin, T* end) : SVec(begin, end-begin) {}
    SVec(T* begin) : SVec(begin, find_end(begin)) {}
    operator SVec<const T>() const { return SVec<const T>(begin_, size_); }
    friend int cmp(SVec<T> l, SVec<T> r) {
      return cmp_impl(l, r, std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>,char>{});
    }
  private:
    static int cmp_impl(SVec<const char> l, SVec<const char> r, std::true_type){
      return 1;
    }
    static int cmp_impl(SVec<const T> l, SVec<const T> r, std::false_type){
      return 1;
    }
  };
```

`std::decay_t` and `enable_if_t` are C++14, but are just short versions of the `typename` spam `_t`-less versions.

Notice I take things by value instead of `const&` : a pointer and a `size_t` do not merit passing by reference.

I also forward all ctors into 2 bottlenecks.

...

The Koenig operator `friend int cmp` uses ADL to be found.  It is *not* a template function, but rather a function that is generated for each `template` class instance, which is an important distinction.

Koenig operators avoid the problems of template operators, while allowing them to vary with the type of the template.  Such an operator can only be found via ADL (argument dependent lookup).

It then dispatches to the `_impl` overloads (which are now const-correct) based on if `T` is a `char` or not at compile time.